Use Motion Canvas without vite
I would like to know if there is some way to work with Motion Canvas without the real-time preview of vite. In my little project, I was trying to create an API where is passes some variables and then is returned the video file based on them.
I tried running it without installing vite as a dependency, and when rendering, the node give an error.
